# Extending a "class" and exporting it via modules

Tags: javascript, browserify, createjs, easeljs

I was following tutorial on tuts+ about game development using easeljs (browserify, bower, grunt). I'm in over my head, nonetheless I was hoping to finish, but part of the tutorials workflow (class model) is now deprecated. This is what createjs team had to say about it: http://blog.createjs.com/new-createjs-class-model/

I don't understand enough, since I didn't know the previous model and TBH trying to get JS to behave OO-like can be a pain.

I have main.js and Button.js based of online demos of easeljs. I would like to extend easeljs Container and export the Button prototype (prototype is JS way of defining a class, is this correct?) and use (create instance of?) it in main.js.

1. Should I use anonymous function to wrap the Button.js file to avoid using global scope or is that not necessary since I am exporting it via its constructor?
2. Is exporting the constructor the preferred way of exporting JS classes?
3. `var p` in Button.js stands for prototype?
4. If I were to create new methods for this class I would do so using `p.newMethod = function() {};` function expression? And when I would create Button instance (`var myButton = new Button("Best button", "green")`) in main.js I could call them like so - `myButton.newMethod;`?
5. Any other corrections and useful light to medium weight content links would be greatly appreciated.

**main.js**

```
'use strict';

var utils = require('./util/index')
    , domReady = utils.domReady
    , Button = require('./Button');

var c = createjs;

console.log('Game started: EaselJS version: ' + c.EaselJS.version);

domReady(function () {
    var stage = new c.Stage('main');

    stage.addChild(new Button("Best button", "green"));

    stage.update();
});
```

**Button.js**

```
 'use strict';

    module.exports = Button;

    function Button(label, color) {
        this.Container_constructor();
        this.color = color;
        this.label = label;

        this.setup();
    }

    var p = createjs.extend(Button, createjs.Container);

    p.setup = function() {
        var text = new createjs.Text(this.label, "20px Arial", "#000");
        text.textBaseline = "top";
        text.textAlign = "center";

        var width = text.getMeasuredWidth()+30;
        var height = text.getMeasuredHeight()+20;

        text.x = width/2;
        text.y = 10;

        var background = new createjs.Shape();
        background.graphics.beginFill(this.color).drawRoundRect(0,0,width,height,10);

        this.addChild(background, text);
        this.cursor = "pointer";

        this.mouseChildren = false;

        this.offset = Math.random()*10;
        this.count = 0;
    };

    window.Button = createjs.promote(Button, "Container");
```

6. Please, don't get all "this question is too broad" on me - it is as straight forward as possible and I would really appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are answers to some of your questions. I don't know anything about using CreateJS content with require.js, so I can't answer your first 2 questions.

3. Yes, the `p` is just a reference to the object prototype, returned by the `createjs.extend` method.
4. Your summary of creating methods on the prototype and calling them is correct.

I wouldn't personally take an inheritance approach with something like this. As you mentioned, inheritance in JavaScript is sort of a mess, so only use it when it makes sense. In your case, I might compose a Container instance, which includes the background and text, and just use `stage.addChild(new Button().container)`. I used the name "container" for the composed content to show the context, but I would probably find something more agnostic, like "instance" or "sprite".

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, I'll dig up more on it. This was actually just experimental stuff, I'm trying to do some game development using JS libraries using OO approach. Did some in vanilla JS, but getting familiar with framework(s) is my current goal. Extra question: how would I define a field (property) of prototype and how would I access it using object instance?

Comment: Properties in JavaScript can be defined on the prototype, but the CreateJS best practice is to define them on the instance (in the constructor). Check out the source in GitHub: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/src/easeljs/display/DisplayObject.js#L150 -- Then you can just access it via the instance: `myObject.alpha`.